# Gaming Branding, Take Three: One Sentence Elevator Pitch

Tags: discussion, top-7, site-attributes, domain-name

In the [latest development](http://blog.stackoverflow.com/2010/10/domain-names-the-wrong-question/) of SE sites' branding, Robert writes:

> > I have a feeling that the real heart of the issue is that everyone thinks naming is hard. That’s not completely true, the truth is finding a .com domain name for a matching good name is hard…
> >
> > Since finding a .com domain naming for a matching site name is so hard, perhaps the community should come up with a good name and later consider which types of domain names they can get for that name. Two distinct things, not one.
> >
> > <sub>[Brian R. Bondy](https://webapps.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/624/672#672)</sub>
>
> It turns out, we, the supposed experts of all things Q&A, had made the most newbie mistake there is — **we’ve been asking the wrong damn question all along!**
>
> We should have asked the community to …
>
> > **Tell us what your community is about in one brief sentence!**

So - what should the tagline for this site be?